# Php- calling static function

Tags: php, mysql, class, function-call

i'm watching a tutorials about CMS with OOP - PHP

i need to know how to Call a public static Function From class in the same file or from including

on control page :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once('globals.php'); 



if(System::Get('db')->Execute("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id`= 2"))
{
    echo "Done";
}
else
{
    echo "No";
}
?>
```

system.php :

```
<?php
class System
{
    //objects array
    private static $objects = array();


    //store object

    public static function Store($index,$value)
    {
        self::$objects[$index] = $value;
    }

    //return object

    public static function Get($index)
    {
        return self::$object[$index];
    }
}
?>
```

globals.php

```
<?php

define('ROOT',dirname(__FILE__));
define('INC',ROOT.'/includes/');
define('CORE',INC.'/core/');
define('MODELS',INC.'/models/');
define('CONTROLLERS',INC.'/controllers/');
define('LIBS',INC.'/libs/');

/*
core files
*/
require_once(CORE.'config.php');
require_once(CORE.'mysql.class.php');
require_once(CORE.'raintpl.class.php');
require_once(CORE.'system.php');

System::Store('db',new mysql());
System::Store('tpl',new RainTPL()); //class RainTPL
?>
```

mysql.php

```
<?php

/*
 * 
 */

/**
 * Description of mysqli
 *
 * @author syam
 */


class mysql {
    private $connection;
    private $last; //last query




    public function __construct() {
        $this->dbconnect();
        $this->Execute('SET NAMES utf8');
    }




    public function dbconnect()
    {

        $this->connection = new mysqli(HOSTNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DBNAME);
        if($this->connection)
            return TRUE;

        return FALSE;
    }





    public function Execute($query)
    {
       //$query = $this->connection->real_escape_string($query);
        if($result = $this->connection->query($query))
        {
            $this->last = $result;
            return TRUE;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

i need more clarification

he is calling the function from class system in this way

```
System::Get('db')->Execute("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id`= 2")
```

i need clarification for this way

and need to know how to call static function in right way

Comment: Have you tried: `$db = System::Get('db');`? Then use it like: `$db->Execute("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id`= 2");`

Comment: i already tried it and found it's simple but i need to understand this line well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By taking a look at your source code we can see System class, which, as defined has got two methods:

Store:

```
self::$objects[$index] = $value;
```

Get:

```
return self::$object[$index];
```

By taking a quick look, you can realize that Get function won't return whatever was stored since objects is not the same array as object. It's a **typo**

With this being fixed, everything should work normally, by using System::Get you simply get a instance from mysql class, and then you just call the method as usual.

EDIT: as requested here's an explanation of this code:

```
System::Get('db')->Execute("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id`= 2")
```

Let's split this in two parts. `System::Get('db')` calls Get static function from System by sending db string as index. As stated in globals.php, a mysql instance is initialized in 'db' index so that would return a mysql element.

Secondly, -> does basically call inner methods of the element, so this means that basically you would be doing something similar to `$mysql->Execute(..)`. In this case, this method requires a string as the query, so you are basically sending it as a parameter which is then executed in mysql.php.

Hope I helped.

Comment: yes it works now but System::Get('db')->Execute("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id`= 2")
 can you explain it ?

Comment: can you explain it more like jeremy because what i need from the question is explaining for this code

Comment: `System::Get('db')->Execute("DELETE FROM users WHERE id= 2")`.

`System::Get('db')` calls Get method sending db as index. If you check globals.php, 'db' index stores a mysql object (as defined by using new mysql() which creates an object).

That returns (you get back) a mysql element. This element has got methods. In your case you decide to use Execute method (which is defined in mysql.php). It requires an argument (string) which you are sending (delete from...). So basically it executes that function. That is basically what is happening in your case.

Thats all I can explain in a comment.

Comment: ok can you add to your answer the explaining ? ,, what i want to be sure from is System::Get('db') will return the value of it ..which an object from mysql class then in my case i can use (->) after Get('db') because Execute is public function ?? to call public function not static i use (->)?? please explain everything in your answer :)

Comment: Edited as requested. Remember to set it as the final answer if it fit your requirements.

Comment: Exactly. -> calls public non-static methods.

Comment: last thing i'm sorry -> for function and attributes like public $last; ?

Comment: If it was public, you would access it by using $element->last

Comment: $element you mean the class :? something like class Pen
{
 public $color; // attribute

Comment: $element means the INSTANCE of the class, not the class itself.

$element = new Pen();

Comment: the object right INSTANCE = object  of class ?

Comment: Exactly. Instance means a object of the class.

Comment: Thanks ;) ,, if i found difficult thing for me in oop  i will make question and type link here for you if you don't mind ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31838215/using-self-or-this?noredirect=1#comment51598135_31838215

Answer (score 0):

To call a static function outer class : 
{Classname}::{StaticFunctionName}();

To call a static function inner class : 
self::{StaticFunctionName}();

Now your specific call :
System::Get('db')->Execute("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id`= 2");
The class System is a static class which manages instances of classes as singloton. So you can call everywhere theses singlotons like 'db';

System::Get('db') : return the singloton of the 'db' class. It's an no-static object.

System::Get('db')->Execute : call the function 'Execute' of the 'db' class.  The 'db' class must be a loadbalancer between differents storages. Your config must be set to mysql. So System::Get('db')->Execute must be call mysql->Execute().

Note : "DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id`= 2" => if 'id' is the primary key, add at the end of query 'LIMIT 1'. It's stop the query after deleting 1 row.

Comment: To call a static function outer class ,, even from another file with including right ?

Comment: The class System is a static class which manages instances of classes as singloton. So you can call everywhere theses singlotons like 'db'; can i ask for more calcification to this point ?

Comment: please when you back answer your explaining what i want from the question :)

Comment: "even from another file with including right ?" Yes, System::get() is public

Comment: "can i ask for more calcification to this point ?" A singloton is a class that can be instantiated only once. So System::get('db') always returns the same object.